# How to properly clean up a table

Tags: mysql

In order to determine how often some object has been used, I use a table with the following fields;

```
id - objectID - timestamp
```

Every time an object is used, it's ID and `time()` are added in. This allows me to determine how often an object has been used in the last hour/minute/second etc.

After one hour, the row is useless (I'm not checking above one hour). However, it is my understanding that it is unwise to simply delete the row, because it may mess up the primary key (auto_increment ID).

So I added a field called "active". Prior to checking how often an object has been used I loop over all `WHERE active=1` and set it to 0 if more than 1 hour has passed. I don't think this would give any concurrency problems between multiple users, but this leaves me with alot of unused data.

Now I'm thinking that maybe it's best to, prior to inserting new usage data, check if there is a field with `active=0` and then rather than inserting a new row, update that one with the new data, and set active to 1 again. However, this would require table locking to prevent multiple clients from updating the same row.

Can anyone shed some more light on this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard anywhere that deleting rows messes up primary keys.

Are you perhaps attempting to ensure that the `id` values automatically assigned by `auto_increment` match those of another table?  This is not necessary - you can simply use an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as the `id` column and assign the values explicitly.

Comment: How do you mean `assign the values explicitly`?

Comment: @MichaelSlade is right (+1 vote). You could use the `objectID` as `Primary Key` (without autoincrement) to make sure you don't have duplicates. You can delete older rows because it won't have any impact. Additionally, you could use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to update the row timestamp if it already exists.

Comment: @mazzucci I think you misunderstand, I *need* duplicate entries per objectID . After all, an object can be used multiple times per hour/minute/second.

Comment: I see. In that case the `Primary Key` would not work. I believe you should keep the current table structure and simply delete or update the older records. If you don't need them in the future, you should perform a delete instead of update, but using a single query instead of looping.

Comment: @mazzucci Someone once told me that removing a row could mess up the primary auto_increment key, and I assumed this was true. I guess not! You know what they say, assumption is the mother of all..

Answer (score 1):

You could execute an update query that match all rows older than 1 hour.

```
UPDATE table SET active=0 WHERE timestamp < now() - interval 1 hour
```

Comment: Good thinking! Why do I always over complicate things? Anyway, is there a chance of two clients selecting the same row? Or is table locking unnecessary for a single query like that?